# Replace apostrophes with regex except if separated by a comma

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that I need to clean up using javascript.

Here below an example of the string that is giving me hell. I need to replace all the occurrences of `'` that are not separated by a comma (like "apostrophe's" in my example).

Here's the example:

```
var paItems = [
  [
    38.20739,
    -85.76427,
    1,
    'asd',
    '314 Iowa Ave, Louisville, KY',
    'this is something with apostrophe's',
    '2000',
    '2',
    '2',
    '1',
    'Yes',
    '',
    '',
    'Area Tennis|Satellite Dish|Controlled Access',
    'asd',
    'asd',
    'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, ',
    'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, ',
    'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, ',
    'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. ',
    ''
  ],
  [
    38.20681,
    -85.71437,
    2,
    'somewhere',
    '3634 Poplar Level Rd, KY ',
    'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard ever since the 1500s, ',
    '1200',
    '3',
    '2',
    '1',
    'Yes',
    'Garage',
    '2250',
    'Private Pool|Area Pool|Satellite Dish',
    '2',
    'Some subdivision here',
    'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. ',
    'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.',
    'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.',
    'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.',
    'Glenda C.'
  ],
];
```

What is the best way to approach it? I've tried regex but can't get it right.

Comment: Please include your attempted code/regex so we can help you find the problem.

Comment: I'm thinking adding something like this at the end:
paItem = paItem.replace(/'/g, "''");

but I don't know how to identify the ones separated by a comma.

Comment: Can you, add a example of a string that need to be replaced and what is the expected result?

Comment: I'm getting this string from a program I didn't build and I can't modify.  I need to plot this as markers on a Google map. I'm thinking the best way to do this is on the javascript that sends this to the markers, but the string is coming with extra apostrophes and crashing.

Comment: Yes, Mindastic, ideally this regex would be able to find only the apostrophes like the one in my example "    'this is something with apostrophe's', " but skip all the other ones that are correctly formatted. Ideally it would replace the invalid apostrophes  with something like " ` " which looks kind of similar to an apostrophe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use:

```
(\w)'(\w)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/iG0jO6/1)

to match apostrophes surrounded by letters, and then replace for example `e's` with `es`, using captured groups(`$1$2`), like in:

```
var str = "'this is something with apostrophe's'";
var res = str.replace(/(\w)'(\w)/g, "$1$2");
```

with result:

> 'this is something with apostrophes'